# Advanced warfare PS3

Tags: ps3, call-of-duty-advanced-warfare

I can't play online or offline with multiplayer it just loads almost to the end then stops. I also can't play any more of the campaign because it keeps saying "Error Image file 13". I just presently updated it and nothing has changed. What do I do??

Comment: have you tried deleting the installed game files and reinstalling them?

Comment: I deleted the game files and downloaded them again but it still freeze just before the game finishes loading. I set here for twenty minutes watching the AW in the corner flash just to see if anything would happen.